# Reset Button for Tic Tac Toe Game (button pops up but doesnt function)

Tags: javascript

i am creating a tic tac toe game using javascript and i got it to work. However my only issue is that the reset button wont work. I have looked at other posts that involve a reset button but im not getting it to work.  Also the function i tried using to for the reset button is document.getElementById("myForm").reset();

I'm  a beginner doing this so im sorry if i made a mistake that seems apparent.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
 <head>
 <title>Tic Tac Toe Game </title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />

 </head>
 
 <style>
  
  
  
  body{
     font-family: san-serif;
     background:#333;
     color:black;
     background-color: yellow;
  }
  td{
      width:80px;
      height:80px;
      border: solid 3px black;
      text-align:center;
      font-size:30pt;
  }

  .tictactoe{
     text-align:center;
     margin:0 auto;
    width:40%;
    padding:10px 50px 20px
    }

  .board{
   float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
   width:60%;
  }

  .player{
     float:left;
     width:15%;
    }

  .player-points{
     font-size:50pt;
  }

  h1{
   
     float: center;
  
  }
   
 </style>
 

<h1 align="center"> Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>
  
 <div class="tictactoe">
 <div class="player">
  Player 1

 <div class="player-points" id="player1">
     0
   </div>
  </div>

  <table id="game" class="board">
  </table>

 <div class="player">
  Player 2
 <div id="player2" class="player-points">0</div>
  </div>
 
 <input type='reset' style='width:100px;margin:0 50%;position:relative;left:-50px;'>
 
 

 <div class="clear"></div>
 
 </div>
 
 
 
 <script>
  var winners = new Array();
//--------------------------------------------------------------- 
 // both player selections are used to keep track of the boxes 
 // that the user has clicked on
  var player1pics = new Array();
  var player2pics = new Array();
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  
  var timer;
  var numberOfPlayers = 2;
  var currentPlayer = 0;
  var move = 0;
  var points1 = 0;    
  var points2 = 0;    
  var gridsize = 3;         // Used for 3x3 Grid


/*
 Function drawboard is manily to check if player 1
 or player 2 has won the round and if one of those 
 players wins, then the points will update
 
 */

function drawBoard() {
    var Parent = document.getElementById("game");
    var counter = 1;
    
    while (Parent.hasChildNodes()) {
        Parent.removeChild(Parent.firstChild);
    }

    for (s = 0; s < 3; s++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        
        for (r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
            var col = document.createElement("td");
            col.id = counter;
            col.innerHTML = counter;

            var handler = function(e) {
                if (currentPlayer == 0) {
                    this.innerHTML = "X";
                    player1pics.push(parseInt(this.id));
                    player1pics.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b });
                }

                else {
                    this.innerHTML = "O";
                    player2pics.push(parseInt(this.id));
                    player2pics.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b });
                }

                move++;
                var isWin = checkWinner();

                if (isWin)
                {
                    if(currentPlayer == 0)
                        points1++;
                    else
                        points2++;

                    document.getElementById("player1").innerHTML = points1;
                    document.getElementById("player2").innerHTML = points2;

                    reset();
                    drawBoard();
                }

                else
                {
                    if (currentPlayer == 0)
                        currentPlayer = 1;
                    else
                        currentPlayer = 0;
                    this.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee);
                }
            };

            col.addEventListener('click', handler);

            row.appendChild(col);
            counter++;
        }

        Parent.appendChild(row);
    }

    loadAnswers();
}

function reset()
{
    currentPlayer = 0;
    player1pics = new Array();
    player2pics = new Array();
}

// Possible ways of Winning
function loadAnswers()
{
    winners.push([1, 2, 3]);
    winners.push([4, 5, 6]);
    winners.push([7, 8, 9]);
    winners.push([1, 4, 7]);
    winners.push([2, 5, 8]);
    winners.push([3, 6, 9]);
    winners.push([1, 5, 9]);
    winners.push([3, 5, 7]);
}

 
//Function checkWinner sees if the player has a winning method by looking at the selections

function checkWinner() {
    
    var win = false;
    var playerSelections = new Array();

    if (currentPlayer == 0)
        playerSelections = player1pics;
    else
 playerSelections = player2pics;
    
    if (playerSelections.length >= gridsize) {
       
        
        for (i = 0; i < winners.length; i++) {
            var sets = winners[i];  
            var setFound = true;
            
            for (r = 0; r < sets.length; r++) {
                var found = false;
                
               
                for (s = 0; s < playerSelections.length; s++) {
                    if (sets[r] == playerSelections[s]) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

              
                if (found == false) {
                    setFound = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (setFound == true) {
                win = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return win;
} 

  

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  drawBoard();
});
  
 </script>
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mitchell,

The click event is not attached to the reset button and the 'drawboard' function isn't called on reset button click. you may have to make the below changes:

```
<input type='reset' style='width:100px;margin:0 50%;position:relative;left:-50px;' onclick="reset()">

function reset()
{
currentPlayer = 0;
player1pics = new Array();
player2pics = new Array();
drawBoard();
}
```